# Minix Internal Fragmentation

Tags: c, inode, minix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internal Fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467053/internal-fragmentation)

I have recently been working on a project to recursively list all files within a directory and output the filename, size and path.

I now need to add the amount of internal fragmentation to the output and then work out the percentage of internal fragmentation within the directory.

I have worked out to do this. I need the inode number (which I get from `stat()`). I then need to follow that inode number and traverse through the inodes to find the last block. I then need to work out how much unused space there is in this block and that will give me the internal fragmentation.

In desperate need of help before I tear out my hair!

Comment: Consider adding the Minix tag to your other question.  It alters things a bit; there are a lot of different file systems on Linux, for example, but probably rather fewer on Minix.